# Freebase suggest - connect with my database?

Tags: jquery, freebase

I'm using [Freebase suggest](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_Suggest). If user cannot find what he is looking for, he types it in the textfield and a new term is added into my database. The thing is, I would like suggest to search also through these added terms.

I found this [answer](http://lists.freebase.com/pipermail/freebase-discuss/2011-May/006513.html), but I am not sure if it suits my needs, because I still want to see Freebase results.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a few more hours of googling and thinking I have figured this out.

I add synchornous ajax call (`'async':false`) to `beforeSend` callback function in the suggest request function. It invokes a function which returns json array of values from my database. After asynchonous call to Freebase suggest service I add the two results together and display them.

That's it!

Comment: That may be OK if your local database is very lightweight/fast, but it'd be better to fire off both requests asynchronously and merge the results when they're both complete so that you only have to wait max(t1,t2) rather than t1+t2.  Something like what is done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538470/jquery-deferred-waiting-for-multiple-ajax-requests-to-finish

Comment: Thank you. Btw you couldn't mark your answer as accepted in first two days otherwise I would do it immediately.