# How to AND jquery promises?

Tags: jquery, promise

I want a promise which will itself resolve when two promises promise1 and promise2 are BOTH resolved. How do I do this?

Here is my current horrible code:

```
            var c = 0;
            var d = $.Deferred();
            promise1.then(() => {
                c++;
                if (c == 2) {
                    d.resolve();
                }
            });
            promise2.then(() => {
                c++;
                if (c == 2) {
                    d.resolve();
                }
            });
            return d.promise();
```

Is there a helper function I can call instead?

Comment: `$.when` does this for you, including proper error handling.

Comment: @Bergi Although in the browser everything tends to be an ajax promise, I certainly didn't think of searching for the answer that way.

Comment: I know, but there were also some other non-ajax questions on this subject (e.g. [Wait for multiple deferred to complete](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14733156/1048572)) closed as duplicates of that canonical question. I guess the keywords were *wait* and *all* or *multiple*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.when](http://api.jQuery.com/jQuery.when/)

Something like

```
$.when(promise1, promise2).then(function() { /* do something */ });
```

This will let you group one or more deferreds and do something only when they have all been resolved. Or calls the `failCallback` if any one of them fails.

When the master deferred resolves, it will be passed the resolved values of all the component deferreds.

Answer (score 2):

**You want jQuery's [`.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).**

Check out the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) for a full example. Here's the gist:

```
$.when( $.ajax("/myURL/"), someOtherDeferred ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
   // ... Both deferrals are complete!
});
```

Note that `$.ajax` creates a "[deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)" (like a `promise`), so the two are interchangeable.

---

*If you want to perform something even if a promise fails, use [`.always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) instead of `.done()`.*

Answer (score 2):

```
$.when(promise1, promise2).then(resolution)
```

Comment: With so much rep, you're definitely the kind of guy who should close as dup instead of being the fastest gun.

Comment: Note the question says "promise" instead of "AJAX". OP may not have known they were interchangeable.

Comment: Shoutout to that explanation

Comment: @CaseyFalk that's something that belongs in a comment

Comment: Fair enough, @Jhawins! :)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Actually, didn't notice. Tired, can't sleep, browsing Stack Overflow, not looking at sidebar, and the answer is a one-liner.