# JavaScript Apply

Tags: javascript

There's an example in [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193398869X) that provides the following code to get around JavaScript's `Math.min()` function, which requires a variable-length list.

```
Example: Math.min(1,2,3,4,5);
```

But, there's a problem if you have a `list: [1,2,3,4,5]`, since you'd rather not have to loop through the list, keeping track of the current min.

The book says to use the following code to solve this issue.

```
function smallest(arr) {
   return Math.min.apply(Math, arr);   
}

alert(smallest([1,2,3,4,5,6,-33]));
```

What happens with `Math.min.apply(Math, arr)` under the hood?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does $.when.apply($, someArray) do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777031/what-does-when-apply-somearray-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the MDN documentation for [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> Calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array (or an array like object).

Answer (score 2):

The [`.apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) "Calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided as an array (or an array like object)."

So basically it works as if you'd passed each item of the array as a separate parameter when calling the function directly.

The first parameter to `.apply()` sets the value of `this` to be used by the function, so your example passes `Math` so that it works the same as if you called it directly as `Math.min(...)`.

Note that you can do the same thing with *any* function:

```
function someFunc(a,b,c,d) { ... }

someFunc(1,2,3,4);
// or
someFunc.apply(null, [1,2,3,4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) allows you to invoke a method on a given instance and provide the arguments as an array. So when you write

```
Math.min.apply(Math, arr);
```

You are invoking the `min` method on the `Math`  class and passing `arr` as arguments.