# How does JavaScript's apply() method work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my head around what JavaScript's `apply()` method actually does. I'm using this as a reference: http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/, in which `apply()` is used to give `Array` a `min()` function.

```
Array.min = function( array ){
    return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};
```

How does `apply()` work here? I get that `Math.min()` can't take an array as an argument, but I'm having trouble visualizing how `apply()` turns the array into a list of arguments that `Math.min` understands.

Comment: I don't understand what sort of answer you are looking for here. `apply` turns the array into an argument list because that is what `apply` is defined as doing in the JavaScript language specification. How it goes about that is an implementation detail which will vary between JavaScript engines.

Comment: Do you know how `apply` works in general?

Comment: Also duplicate of [JavaScript Apply](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14791987/1048572)

Comment: @Quentin, you know, I'm not sure. I'm always weary of thinking I understand things, so I just use StackOverflow as a place to check what I think I know. I think, though, I'd like to see the source code for `apply()` to understand the actual logic that goes into making it work. Or, maybe, I'll try to code up my own version and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what the `apply` method does. It calls the method with the array items as parameters.

Using `Math.min.apply(Math, [ 1, 2, 3 ])` is the same as `Math.min(1, 2, 3)`.

There is nothing special with making it work for the `Math.min` method, it works the same for any function. Using `myFunction.apply(window, ['a','b'])` does the same thing as `myFunction('a', 'b')`.