# Free Code Camp: TWITCH TV API: Trying to move everything from getJSONs to AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So here's my codepen:
http://codepen.io/muzzotech/pen/mAodAv

Twitch's API now requires Client ID tokens so I had to change all of my getJSON's over to AJAX requests, but it isn't working. None of the followers are appearing below the headers of the html. When I run javascript console, I get two kinds of errors. The first is that `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/+ following[i] + "/?callback=?"`gives me a `400 Bad Request` (It also does if I remove the slash so that it reads `"?callback=?"`) and I get the "`pen.js:77 Uncaught ReferenceError: data3 is not defined`" where it tries to use "data3._links.channel" as the URL. I'm rather new to all of this so I would love some direction with this.

Also, there was a section that originally had a $.getJSON.done part but I don't know how to put that into AJAX.

Comment: There are nested `$.ajax()` calls within nested `for` loops at `javascript` at codepen, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example/. Try substituting `$.map()` for `for` loops, using `$.when.apply()` pattern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777031/what-does-when-apply-somearray-do?s=2|2.2304. Can you include `html`, `javascript` at Question?

Comment: I just saw you updated your response. I will include html & javascript with the question. Thanks.

Comment: How do I substitute the for loops with $.map()'s.

Comment: Please don't add all of the tags to the title. It is unnecessary and makes it harder to know what your question is, especially when you make them all uppercase. Also, you should include a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah, I fixed the data1.stream thing. The expected URL's are like `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/noobs2ninjas?callback=?` and they are for showing the icon, username and status of each person on or offline.

Comment: @muzzo The correct URL is being passed. Though server appears to not expect that request

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Changed the question title to best fit the question. Thanks.

Comment: @guest271314: I did that in order to go if the callback is like "hey, this isn't what we're looking for" then it should be okay. Apparently, it is not.

Comment: Was able to perform successful request, though there is no `follows` property at `data2` object. Also, you should probably pass parameters to `follows()` call within `success` handler

Comment: Actually, there is a `.follows` property at `data2`. Though there are no `.error` properties

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126556/discussion-between-guest271314-and-muzzo).

Answer (score 1):

Substituting `$.when.apply()`, `$.map()` for `for` loops. Note, no `.error` property is set at any of the returned objects. Set `contentType` to `"json"` at `$.ajaxSetup()`, set `dataType` to `"json"` at `$.ajax()` requests.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var following = [];
  var logo;
  var status;
  var name;

  function follower(logo, name, status) {
    $("#followerInfo").prepend("<div class = 'row'>" + "<div class='col-md-4>" + "<img src='" + logo + "'>" + "</div>" + "<div class='col-md-4>" + name + "</div>" + "<div class='col-md-4>" + status + "</div></div>");
  }

  $.ajaxSetup({
    contentType: "json"
  })


  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType:"json",
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp",
    headers: {
      'Client-ID': 'rp0e2c4y3nqc392dgwehvbhg0cs5r8c'
    },
    success: function(data1) {
      console.log(data1);
      if (data1.stream === null) {
        $("#fccStatus").html("Free Code Camp is Currently OFFLINE");
      } else {
        $("#fccStatus").html("Free Code Camp is Currently ONLINE");
      }
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType:"json",
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/freecodecamp/follows/channels/",
    headers: {
      'Client-ID': 'rp0e2c4y3nqc392dgwehvbhg0cs5r8c'
    },
    success: function(data2) {
      console.log(data2);
      for (var i = 0; i < data2.follows.length; i++) {
        var displayName = data2.follows[i].channel.display_name;
        following.push(displayName);
      }

      $.when.apply($, $.map(following, function(_following) {
        return $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + _following /* + "?callback=?" */,
          headers: {
            'Client-ID': 'rp0e2c4y3nqc392dgwehvbhg0cs5r8c'
          },
          success: function(data3) {
            if (data3.error) {
              logo = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Thomas_Organ_Crybaby.jpg/180px-Thomas_Organ_Crybaby.jpg";
              name = data3.message;
              status = data3.error;
              follower(log, name, status);
            }

            if (data3.stream === null) {
              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType:"json",
                url: data3._links.channel,
                headers: {
                  'Client-ID': 'rp0e2c4y3nqc392dgwehvbhg0cs5r8c'
                },
                success: function(data4) {
                  if (data4.error) {
                    status = "OFFLINE";
                    logo = data4.logo;
                    name = data4.display_name;
                    if (logo === null) {
                      logo = "http://images.allposters.com/images/ATA/24802BP.jpg";
                    }
                    follower(logo, name, status);
                  }
                }

              });
            }
          }
        });
      }));

      $.when.apply($, $.map(following, function(_following) {
        return $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          dataType:"json",
          url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + _following,
          headers: {
            'Client-ID': 'rp0e2c4y3nqc392dgwehvbhg0cs5r8c'
          },
          success: function(data5) {
            console.log(data5);
            if (data5.error) {
              logo = data4.stream.channel.logo;
              status = data4.stream.channel.status;
              name = data4.stream.channel.display_name;
              follower(logo, name, status);
            }
          }

        });

      }));
    }
    });
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/NXYRweuIdv6sQrUnqkWX?p=preview

Comment: That brings me back to the main issue which is the logos, names, and statuses of each person isn't showing up on screen.

Comment: There is no `.error` property at returned `dataN` object. What should occur if  `dataN` does not have a `.error` property and `dataN.stream` is `null`?