# how jszip async zip file when a lot of single file need to zip

Tags: jszip

i am not good at  english,but i have a question about use jszip. the code like this

```html
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    compressFiles(files[i], compressName);
                }
```

```html
    function compressFiles(file,compressName) {
        var fileContent = file.file;
        var fileName = file.name;
        var zip = new JSZip();
        zip.file(fileName, fileContent);
        zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
            saveAs(content, compressName);
        });
    }
```

my question is when my file in files are very big ,about 88m.  some file compress are about 0m i guess the reason is async,the loop put file stream into memory one by one,if the memory is full,compress filed. so who can tell me the real reason?thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to keep the zip.file calls and jQuery.when to wait for all of them to finish, and then call zip.generateAsync. Sample code below.

Helpful links:
[jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)
[What does $.when.apply($, someArray) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777031/what-does-when-apply-somearray-do)

```
function zipFiles(images) {
    var zip = new JSZip();
    deferreds = [];
    images.forEach(function(image) {
        deferreds.push(zip.file(image.name, image.data, { binary: true }));
    });
    $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {
        zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function(content) {
            saveAs(content, 'Filename.zip'); //FileSaver.js
        });
    });
}
```