# Making while for checking the value is correct or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, for-loop, while-loop

I have 2 variable and i want to do something when they changed to same value like each other.
So this is my code:

```
var val_1,val_2;
for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
    readyforgo++;
    $.post("somewhere.php",{
        something: something
    },function(data, status){
        readytogo++;
    });
}
if(readyforgo==readytogo){
    alert(1);
}
```

Its not gonna return 1 because my if is working faster than my `$.post` i mean i want some code like this :

```
function checker(){
    if(readyforgo==readytogo){
        alert(1);
    }else{
        setTimeout(function(){checker();},100);
    }
}
checker();
```

Its working as well but i looking for something better i mean i don't want to use any code like that because its using cpu and ram until trying to get `readyforgo==readytogo` do we have code like this? 
i don't like to use setTimeout or setInvertal or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Promise.all(promises)`.

- Your $.post would need to be adapted to create a promise unless it already returns one.  (See comment from georg)
- You would put each promise into an array.
- Promise.all will be invoked after all async calls complete.

```
const promises = []
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
  // assuming your post returns a promise
  promises.push($.post("somewhere.php"))
}
Promise.all(promises).then(results=>{
  // your code here
})
```

If your code is in an `async` block, you can do the following and avoid nested functions:

```
results = await Promise.all(promises)
// your code here
})
```

This pattern of waiting on all promises is very common after dispatching multiple async calls.

Comment: @Andy for the record, One can use promisify or a simple manual wrapper.  I could post it, but there are many solutions for that on SO.  And as it turns out, not needed in this case.

Comment: `Promises.all` is not working but `Promis.all` is working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check when all the posts have either been resolved/rejected you could take advantage of how jQuery's deferred objects (similar to promises) work. Create an array of jQuery deferred objects and then use [`when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to wait until they've all resolved/rejected.

```
// Create an array of POST deferred objects
function getDeferreds() {
  const deferreds = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    deferreds.push($.post("somewhere.php", { something: something }));
  }
  return deferreds;
}

// $.when works similarly to Promise.all
$.when.apply(null, getDeferreds()).then(data => {
  alert(1);
});
```

[Here's a good explanation why `apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14777167/1377002) has been used in this example.