# jQuery Deferred - waiting for dynamic async requests to finish all even if some failed

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I got a dynamic asynchronous request (for the jsfiddle I used ajax) that I need to wait regardless of success or failure, which means I only need to know that all are processes are finished even if some request failed.

//Dynamic: In my case this is produced by an ajax request so the number of followup async request is flexible

So I originally used this code:

```
    $.when.apply($,deferreds).done(function() {
        $("div").append("<p>All done!</p>");
    }).fail(function(){
        $("div").append("<p>Something failed!</p>");
    });
```

But in the scenario that one of the deferred failed, the fail callback will be called immediately. I tried changing it to [always()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) but the result is:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'always'**

So how can I implement an always() kind of solution for this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marlberm2014/ekGeA/2/)

My original source: [jQuery Deferred - waiting for multiple AJAX requests to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538470/jquery-deferred-waiting-for-multiple-ajax-requests-to-finish)

Comment: I'd suggest using a custom deferred that counts success and fail then resolves at end, though .always should work here too.

Comment: Like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/marlberm2014/ekGeA/4/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want to wait a list of `$.Deferred` to end regardless they are `rejected` or `resolved`, you have the solution in my answer in your original source [jQuery Deferred - waiting for multiple AJAX requests to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538470/jquery-deferred-waiting-for-multiple-ajax-requests-to-finish/13627555#13627555) :

```
$.when.apply($, $.map(deferreds, function(d) {
    var wrapDeferred = $.Deferred();
    // you can add .done and .fail if you want to keep track of each results individualy
    d.always(function() { wrapDeferred.resolve(); });
    return wrapDeferred.promise();
}));
```

Comment: Damn, the answer is already in the source. 0_0
I didn't saw that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I'm not really a Javascript coder and this saved my life! Do you know how I can then work out which ones worked and which ones failed (and why)?

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on the last line, should be }));

Answer (score 0):

Ok like what [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) suggested. I used a custom deferred that will be resolve no matter the outcome of the asynch request.

```
var deferreds = $.map(i, function (count, index){
    var waitingProcess = new $.Deferred(); //Here is the custom deferred
    if(count == 7) {
        $.Deferred().fail(function(){
            $("div").append("<p>Task #" + count + " failed.");
            waitingProcess.resolve(); //resolve it no matter the outcome
        }).reject();
    }else{
        $.post('/echo/html/', {
            html: "<p>Task #" + count + " complete.",
            delay: count
        }).success(function(data) {
            $("div").append(data);
            waitingProcess.resolve(); //resolve it no matter the outcome
        });
    }
    return waitingProcess.promise();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marlberm2014/ekGeA/4/)

Comment: Where's that magic number 7 coming from? can it be calculated instead?

Comment: It only simulate the case where one of the request failed.