# How can I make sure all AJAX requests have completed before running a new function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, twitter, jsonp

I'm creating an app that displays tweets based on names the user selects from a form. The selections are passed to the "getTweets" function, like this:

```
function getTweets(selections) {

    var holdTweets = [];

    $.each( selections, function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/'+this.id+'.json?callback=?',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) { holdTweets.push(this); },
            error: function() { console.log('something went wrong'); }
        });

    });
}
```

After all of the AJAX requests have completed, I want to sort the holdTweets array before parsing the JSON.

Everything works fine at first: The AJAX requests are returning the JSON and the holdTweets array is being populated. Is it possible to check if all AJAX requests have completed before doing the sorting? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the rocket science? Remember how many requests you've issued, and how many have completed. When you've issued all the requests, and the number of completed requests matches it, et voila, they're all done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Deferred - waiting for multiple AJAX requests to finish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538470/jquery-deferred-waiting-for-multiple-ajax-requests-to-finish)

Comment: Just compute the length of selections, and add a setInterval to check when the length of AJAX calls in holdTweets = the length of selections

Comment: No need for a set interval, just use the complete callback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys. I've done this, and it's working fine.

```
function getTweets(selections) {

    var holdTweets = [];

    $.each( selections, function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/'+this.id+'.json?callback=?',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) { 
                holdTweets.push(this);
                if(holdTweets.length === selections.length) { 
                    sortFunction(holdTweets); 
                }
            },
            error: function() { console.log('something went wrong'); }
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery, the [ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) method allows you to register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed.