# Multiple ajax request in sequence using recursive function and execute callback function after all requests completed

Tags: javascript, ajax, recursion

I have list of names separated by comma. What I want is I want to call server request for all names in a sequence and store result inside an array. I tried and it's working when I do have number of names which are there in string.

See [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/obkp6Lg0/2/) - This is working when I know number of names

Now what I want is I want to make this code as generic. If I add one name in that string, It should handle automatically without adding any code for ajax request.

See [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/obkp6Lg0/4/) - This is what I've tried. It's not working as expected.

```
shoppingList = shoppingList.split(",");
var result = [];

function fetchData(shoppingItem)
{
    var s1 = $.ajax('/items/'+shoppingItem);
    s1.then(function(res) {
        result.push(new Item(res.label,res.price));
        console.log("works fine");
    });
    if(shoppingList.length == 0)
    {
        completeCallback(result);
    }
    else
    {
        fetchData(shoppingList.splice(0,1)[0]);
    }
}

fetchData(shoppingList.splice(0,1)[0]);
```

**Problem**

I am not getting how to detect that all promise object have been resolved so that I can call callback function.

Comment: Notice the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) in your first solution, it should be just http://jsfiddle.net/obkp6Lg0/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the ajax requests in sequence, you have to put the recursive call in the callback:

```
function fetchList(shoppingList, completeCallback) {
    var result = [];
    function fetchData() {
        if (shoppingList.length == 0) {
            completeCallback(result);
        } else {
            $.ajax('/items/'+shoppingList.shift()).then(function(res) {
                result.push(new Item(res.label,res.price));
                console.log("works fine");
                fetchData();
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^
            });
        }
    }
    fetchData();
}
```

or you actually use promises and do

```
function fetchList(shoppingList) {
    return shoppingList.reduce(function(resultPromise, shoppingItem) {
        return resultPromise.then(function(result) {
            return $.ajax('/items/'+shoppingItem).then(function(res) {
                result.push(new Item(res.label,res.price));
                return result;
            });
        });
    }, $.when([]));
}
```

([updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obkp6Lg0/6/))

---

Notice there is nothing in the requirements of the task about the ajax requests to be made sequentially. You could also let them run in parallel and [wait for all of them to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6538470/1048572):

```
function fetchList(shoppingList) {
    $.when.apply($, shoppingList.map(function(shoppingItem) {
        return $.ajax('/items/'+shoppingItem).then(function(res) {
            return new Item(res.label,res.price);
        });
    })).then(function() {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    })
}
```

([updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obkp6Lg0/7/))

Comment: It looks correct but I find it very complex to understand. Can you please update my fiddle code so that I can understand. I want to use second approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
// global:
var pendingRequests = 0;

// after each ajax request:
pendingRequests++;

// inside the callback:
if (--pendingRequest == 0) {
    // all requests have completed
}
```

Comment: It's same as checking length of array which I did. I don't think it will help. Can you please update my fiddle and show me how will it work?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to minimal to make it work - [`Click here`](http://jsfiddle.net/eje1jvu5/12/).

Please note your last assertion will fail as the item promise is not resolved in linear manner. Thus sequence of the item will change.