# Jquery Ajax call in a loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to make a call to the server and get batches of 50 records back. I need to do this untill I've had all records. Can somebody help out of this

```
var stillRecordsAvailable = true;
var start = 1;
   while (stillRecordsAvailable) {
   // get the next batch of records
   $.ajax({
      url: '/getData?start='+start+'&recordLimit=50',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        if(data.records == 0){
           stillRecordsAvailable = false;
        }
        else{
          start += 50;
        // do something
        }    
      },
      error: function(data) {
       // nothing left to do
      stillRecordsAvailable = false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried anything till now??..Show some efforts first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538470/jquery-deferred-waiting-for-multiple-ajax-requests-to-finish

Comment: @Shiva not satisfying my requirerment

Comment: @sunil44: Please specify your requirements clearly.

Comment: I am accessing records from server in a batch of 50 records per ajax call. but i don't know how much records exists. So i need to break loop after empty response received and also want to increment start variable by 50 in query param to point to next 5o th record

Comment: @Shiva I just edited my code according to requirements plz have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using recursion, Call same method until you get all records.

```
// get the next batch of records
var callServer = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/getrecords.json',
    data: {
      data_set_id: dataset.id
    },
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.records != 0) {
        callServer();//Make ajax call again for next records.
      }

      // do something
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // nothing left to do

    }
  });
}
callServer();
```

Comment: I tried with recursion, but it will cause memory leakage problem as i am having more than 30000 records for a datasetId

Comment: call recursion method using setTimeout, this might help u