# JQuery: Single callback for multiple AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've read a lot of threads on here and haven't found an answer that satisfies my problem.

Basically I'm building *n* AJAX calls and want to do something only once they've *all* returned.

But whatever I try, `done()` the callback fires too early. Here's my code:

```
    // turn the URL array into an AJAX request array
    for (var i=0; i<mediaRequests.length; i++) {
        mediaRequests[i] = $.ajax(mediaRequests[i], {dataType: 'jsonp'});
    }

    $.when($, mediaRequests).done(function() {
        var responses = arguments[1];

        // for each response...
        for (var i=0; i<responses.length; i++) {
            var data = responses[i].responseJSON;
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

But the console prints out `undefined`.

Why isn't `$.when($, mediaRequests).done()` giving me the responses?

Comment: There's been a similar question already (with a valid answer):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538470/jquery-deferred-waiting-for-multiple-ajax-requests-to-finish

Answer (score 0):

Hello you could use defferreds array with apply like this :

```
$.when.apply($, mediaRequests).done(function(){
```

Instead of:

```
$.when($, mediaRequests).done(function() {
```

When you know how many ajaxes you are calling you can do this (lets say there are 3 of them):

```
$.when.apply($, mediaRequests).done(function(result1,result2,result3){
// now result1 got result from first ajax, result2 from second ajax and so on
```

Comment: Ok now I get `Object {pagination: Object, data: Array(20), meta: Object}` but when I try to access `responseJSON.data` I get undefined get `undefined` again

Comment: Its because you are not returning the ajax. I will edit my answer ok?

Comment: sure, go ahead.

Comment: Btw where did you get arguments from? Where are they defined?