# How to get the two parameters of two asynchronous functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
var o = new X();
o.setFooCallback1(function(result1){
});
o.setFooCallback2(function(result2){
});
o.foo("xxx");
```

as you can see, when I call `o.foo()`, there're two callbacks will be fired with two results, `result1` and `result2`, what I want to  do is use pass `result1` and `result2` to my constructor function to create an object:

```
var y = new Y(result1, result2);
```

But result1 and result2 come in different time(asynchronous)， how could I handle this?
ps: the class `X` is from others' library, I can't modify it's implemention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement what is known as the [semaphore pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_semaphore)

Here is a hands-on implementation:

```
var o = new X()
  , n = 0
  , result1, result2

function checkResults(){
    if (--n > 0) return;
    var y = new Y(result1, result2)
}

o.setFooCallback1(function(res){
    result1 = res
    checkResults()
})

o.setFooCallback2(function(res){
    result2 = res
    checkResults()
})
```

Or an object-oriented approach:

```
function Semaphore(callback){
    this.callback = callback
    this.count = 0
    this.args = []
}
Semaphore.prototype.check = function(){
    if (--this.count <= 0)
        this.callback.apply(null, this.args)
}
Semaphore.prototype.queue = function(){
    var self = this
    self.count++
    return function(res){
        self.args.push(res)
        self.check()
    }
}

var fooResults = new Semaphore(function(res1, res2){
    var y = new Y(res1, res2)
})

o.setFooCallback1(fooResults.queue())
o.setFooCallback2(fooResults.queue())
```

Note that it only captures the first callback arguments, but you can easily extend this to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to add another layer, that fires a callback after both callbacks from the first layer have executed, probably in a different object. The answer here is pretty good:

[jQuery callback for multiple ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368946/javascript-callback-for-multiple-ajax-calls)

Answer (score 0):

Call the same function from, inside both callbacks, but only actually do anything once they have both returned, like this:

```
(function(){
  var y, r1, r2;

  function runWhenBothReturn() {
    if(r1 && r2) { //check both are set to a non-falsy value
      y = new Y(r1, r2); 
    }
  }

  var o = new X();

  o.setFooCallback1(function(result1){
    r1 = result1;
    runWhenBothReturn();
  });

  o.setFooCallback2(function(result2){
    r2 = result21;
    runWhenBothReturn();
  });

  o.foo("xxx"); 

})();
```

Notice that i have added a closure so that `y`, `r1` and `r2` doesn't become global variables, but stay local to the task.

If either `r1` or `r2` can have values that evaluate to false, then make sure to update the if sentence accordingly :)