# send form data to two pages via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms, mysqli

im having a little problem here, i have a form, with 2 fields, i need the form to redirect me to a specifil location, for example to 1.php, and i need the values from the form to be sent to 2.php all at once, with php i couldnt do it, im guessing with ajax this can be done, any ideas?

```
 <form action="1.php">
 <input type="text" name="value1">
 <input type="text" name="value2">
 </form>
```

Why im doing this? this is a search form, i have a jquery pagination on the form action, but the pagination gets the data from 2.php, that is where i need the data to be sent also, i need it to be in 1.php and 2.php

ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just include 2.php in 1.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same by sending data asynchronously to the other page by HTML5 FormData.
Here's the code :

```
<form action="1.php" onsubmit="sendData()" id="myForm">
 <input type="text" name="value1">
 <input type="text" name="value2">
</form>

<script>
function sendData()
{
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('myForm'));
$.ajax({
    url: '2.php',  //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',  //POST or GET
    xhr: function()
    {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
    },

    data: formData,  //form data

    //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you use JQuery. Please check out these pages, perhaps these may help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/599349/jQuery-Execute-Run-Multiple-Ajax-Requests-Simultan
[jQuery callback for multiple ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368946/javascript-callback-for-multiple-ajax-calls)