# jQuery: Determine whether multiple events have ALL been triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am using custom triggered events after asynchronous calls happen, and I need a way to determine when they've ALL been triggered.

For example:

```
var ajaxFunction1 = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl.html",
        complete: function(){
            //Ok, all done
            $(document).trigger('ajaxFunction1Finished')
        }
    })
}

var ajaxFunction2 = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl.html",
        complete: function(){
            //Ok, all done
            $(document).trigger('ajaxFunction2Finished')
        }
    })
}

var ajaxFunction3 = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl.html",
        complete: function(){
            //Ok, all done
            $(document).trigger('ajaxFunction3Finished')
        }
    })
}

ajaxFunction1();
ajaxFunction2();
ajaxFunction3();

jQuery
   .when( /* Whenever $(document) receives those three events */ )
   .done(function(){
      //Do something
   })
```

Is this possible? I'd like to avoid triggering new events just to get a return true.

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368946/javascript-callback-for-multiple-ajax-calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the triggers doing anything special?

```
var oneDone = false;
var twoDone = false;
var threeDone = false;

function checkIfEverythingIsDone() {
   if (oneDone && twoDone && threeDone) {
     // everything is done and you may proceed
   }
}

var ajaxFunction1 = function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "someUrl.html",
    complete: function(){
      oneDone = true;
      checkIfEverythingIsDone();
    }
  })
}

var ajaxFunction2 = function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "someUrl.html",
    complete: function(){
      twoDone = true;
      checkIfEverythingIsDone();
    }
  })
}

var ajaxFunction3 = function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "someUrl.html",
    complete: function(){
      threeDone = true;
      checkIfEverythingIsDone();
    }
  })
}

ajaxFunction1();
ajaxFunction2();
ajaxFunction3();
```

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may help -

```
var requestCompletedArray = [];

/* assuming i have `n` ajax calls to make */
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl.html",
        complete: callback
    })
}

/* my callback definition */
function callback(data) {
    if(requestCompletedArray.length < n-1) {
        requestCompletedArray.push(data.status);
        return;
    } else if(requestCompletedArray.length === n-1) {
        //do something, all requests are completed
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work for the example code I posted, true. However, I need to be able to avoid the case where one of the events is triggered twice. In other words, your solution works, but only if I can guarantee that each triggered event gets triggered only once.