# jQuery $.each nested in $.When

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of itens to pass through a function that returns a `$.ajax()` but the `.done` is getting called after the `$.each` is called, not after the inners ajax calls complete! What should I do?!?

Here is my code:

```
$.when(
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        GetReservation(
            item.UniqueId,
            apiRoot,
            //this is the 'success' function
            function (data2) {
                //do my stuff
            },
            //this is the 'error' function
            function (x, y, z) {
                if (x.status == 404) {
                    //OK, no reservations!
                }
            });
    })
).done(setButtons(box, c));
```

Comment: It is expected behavior ...add handler to ajax .

Comment: this may be relevant [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: As far as I know; when you use `$.when` the all youre promises should be successfull for the `$.when` to return done.

Comment: @Liam not really..It could be relevant but not really duplicate.

Comment: Look here: [Javascript callback for multiple ajax calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368946/javascript-callback-for-multiple-ajax-calls)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.each` is not returning an array of promises as your code seems to be expecting. You should build an array of promises first then call `$.when` with your array:

```
var promises = [];

$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    // add promise to array
    promises.push(GetReservation(
        item.UniqueId,
        apiRoot,
        //this is the 'success' function
        function (data2) {
            //do my stuff
        },
        //this is the 'error' function
        function (x, y, z) {
            if (x.status == 404) {
                //OK, no reservations!
            }
        }
    ));
})

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(){
  setButtons(box, c)
});
```

Comment: problem persists... setButtons still getting called before GetReservation done...

Comment: I saw the problem immediately, setButtons was being invoked immediately and needed to be wrapped in a function. I've updated my example

Comment: Also, make sure your `GetReservation` function is returning the promise.

Comment: Without looking at more of your source code (specifically the `GetReservation` function, it's hard to say. Calling `$.when` in this manner will definitely work if you are using an array of promises, for example: `$.when.apply($, [$.get('example.html'), $.ajax({..})]).done(..)`. So assuming `GetReservation` is doing something like `return $.ajax(...)` it should be working.