# Why does deferred.when() return promises in done callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

Why is jQuery's `deferred.when` returning promises in the `done` callback, rather than their corresponding response data?

```
var data = {
    json: JSON.stringify({
        text: 'some text',
        array: [1, 2, 'three'],
        object: {
            par1: 'another text',
            par2: [3, 2, 'one'],
            par3: {}
        }
    }),
    delay: 3
};

var firstRequest =  $.ajax({
    url:'/echo/json/',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST'
});

var secondRequest =  $.ajax({
    url:'/echo/json/',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST'
});

$.when.apply($, [firstRequest, secondRequest]).done(function(data1, data2){
    console.log(data1); // returns array, I expect a response object
    console.log(data2); 
});
```

Both the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) and various answers on SO, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200237/598511), implies that I should get the actual response objects, rather than arrays with `[responseobject, textstatus, jqxhr]`.

http://jsfiddle.net/2h48mr78/

Comment: Uh, read the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) again. The example with the `$.ajax` calls explicitly explains that "*Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]*"

Comment: @Bergi Wops, sometimes you need two sets of eyes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the correct structure back, however the `data1` and `data2` arguments isn't the actual data itself. It's actually an array with three items, the `data, statusText, jqXHR` so your data is actually in `data1[0]` which will log out:

```
Object {text: "some text", array: Array[3], object: Object}
```

The documentation is a bit unclear but shows how it works in the Example section.

Comment: I have seen that, what bothers me is the inconsistency. To elaborate, you can't rely on the array structure. What if you pass a custom promise: http://jsfiddle.net/2h48mr78/4/ I was hoping to find the response object regardless.

Comment: You should look at other promise implementations for that.

Comment: @Johan this is fixed in jQuery 3.0 for what it's worth.