# Combine multiple Ajax load functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, highcharts

I am making a dashboard reporting tool that loads multiple charts on the selection of some filters. I use `Ajax` to load the charts and use [Ajaxload](http://www.ajaxload.info/) to have a small circle as a waiting symbol. Something like: [image]

I want to combine all those circles into one circle in the center, like any normal ecommerce website.
The ajax code is below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "jsontring": JSON.stringify(output)
    },
    url: "http://localhost:8080/sales",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#container').html("<img class = 'ajload' src='loading.gif' />");
        $('#container1').html("<img class = 'ajload' src='loading.gif' />");
    },

    success: function (data) {
        datavol = data.Vol
        dataval = data.Val
        $('#container').highcharts(datavol);
        $('#container1').highcharts(dataval);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Sales Issue!")
    },

});


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/soc",
    data: {
        "jsontring": JSON.stringify(output)
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#container3').html("<img class = 'ajload' src='loading.gif' />");
        $('#container4').html("<img class = 'ajload' src='loading.gif' />");
    },

    success: function (data) {
        datavol = data.Vol
        dataval = data.Val
        $('#container3').highcharts(datavol);
        $('#container4').highcharts(dataval);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Soc Issue")
    },

});




$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/marketshares",
    data: {
        "jsontring": JSON.stringify(output)
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#marketshares').html("<img class = 'ajload' src='loading.gif' />");
        $('#marketshares1').html("<img class = 'ajload' src='loading.gif' />");
    },

    success: function (data) {
        datavol = data.Vol
        dataval = data.Val
        $('#marketshares').highcharts(datavol);
        $('#marketshares1').highcharts(dataval);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("MarketShares Issues")
    },

});
```

Is there any specific fucnctiuon for this?

Comment: You are loading the image into different div it's unclear what you want, just use the same container.

Comment: create an overlay div with the proper css and the loading symbol and then call it before AJAX call.

Comment: so you want to show loading image until all ajax success?

Comment: So basically there is a time difference between the loading of the charts. Some take 2 secs and some take 5. I want the waiting symbol to be present until the last ajax call is passed and then all the carts to be displayed at the same time.

Comment: @Rasel Yes that is exactly what I want.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368946/javascript-callback-for-multiple-ajax-calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Ajaxcomplete() Description:** Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete. This is an AjaxEvent.

1. You have to create an overlay and center load div, See **[Exmaple Here](http://codepen.io/MattIn4D/pen/LiKFC)**, e.g :

   ```
   <div class="loading">Loading</div>
   ```
2. You have after that to create a global variable e.g `var count=0` and increment this variable in every success function e.g `count++;` :

   ```
   success: function (data) {
         .....
         count++;
   }
   ```
3. After that You can use a condition inside **[Ajaxcomplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)** function that execute after every ajax request e.g :

   ```
   $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
     if(count == 3) //I guess that you have 3 chart to load
        $('.loading').hide();
   });
   ```

**NOTE :** You can remove the `beforeSend()`.

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: That was a very very detailed answer, definitely helpful for a beginner like me :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure! I am checking it now.

Answer (score 2):

Take a global `var` for number of ajax call;

`isLoadedAll=4;`//4 ,let 4 is the number of `$.ajax` call.

Use one container for loading image.
After a success call a function that checks all ajax success.

```
 function checkAllLoaded(){
--isLoadedAll;
if(isLoadedAll==0)
    //do stop loading image here.
}
```

before send

```
beforeSend: function() {
        $('#container').html("<img class = 'ajload' src='loading.gif' />");
        $('#container1').html("<img class = 'ajload' src='loading.gif' />");
}
```

on each success

```
success: function(data)
         {
              checkAllLoaded();
              //do other stuff here
         }
```

hope that help.

Comment: Thank ypou so much for that solution. Probably I am very new to understand this. Is `checkAllLoaded` a built in function? I am not really clear with that part.

Answer (score 1):

First load your ajax loader image as:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        //here call your ajax loader image
});
```

And after ajax complete hide your loader image

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.when($.ajax(...), $.ajax(...)).then(function (resp1, resp2) {
    //this callback will be fired once all ajax calls have finished.
    // here hide your ajax loader image
  });
});
```

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368946/javascript-callback-for-multiple-ajax-calls)