# Push response (social share counts) from $.getJSON to array and use this array into other function

Tags: javascript, json, twitter, vk

Try to make array with share counters for current URL of three social networks: Twitter, Facebook & VK. I need to get sum of all elements of this array and display result (into other function).

Array must be something like this `[1, 2, 3]`.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var totalCount = new Array();

  // Twitter counter
  $.getJSON('http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&callback=?', function(response) {
    totalCount.push(response.count); // try to push response.count to array
  });

  // Facebook counter
  $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href), function(response) {
    totalCount.push(response.shares); // try to push response.shares to array
  });

  // VK counter
  $.getJSON('https://vk.com/share.php?act=count&index=1&url=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&callback=?', function(response) {});
  VK = {};
  VK.Share = {};
  VK.Share.count = function(index, count) { 
    totalCount.push(count); // try to push count to array
  };

  // Show array
  console.log(totalCount);

});
```

But this code is empty (show `[]` in Chrome console).

Any ideas? Help me please.

Comment: The `$.getJSON()` operations are asynchronous. Results will not be available until the underlying HTTP transactions are complete.

Comment: I guess you want to look into this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4368946/218196

Comment: Is there any way to make sum of the values of these ``$.getJSON()`` functions?