# For loop for ajax calling returning end value

Tags: jquery, ajax

On condition calling Ajax, but it is returning last value.

Here is my code

```
if(f_ref==209){
        array1=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
        for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            console.log("loop", array1[i], i, array1.length);
            getvalue = array1[i];
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "/getReportData",
                data: { getvalue:getvalue},
                //cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result.length);
                    resultarr=result;
                    console.log(resultarr.length);
                    console.log(i);
                    if(i==0){
                        $("#1").val(resultarr.length);
                        console.log(resultarr.length);
                    }
                    else if(i==1){$("#2").val(resultarr.length);}
                    else if(i==2){$("#3").val(resultarr.length);}
                    else if(i==3){$("#4").val(resultarr.length);}
                    else if(i==4){$("#5").val(resultarr.length);}
                    else if(i==5){$("#6").val(resultarr.length);}                      
                },
                error: function(error) {
            
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });            
          }
    }
```

On if condition true it goes inside, Assign array1 values.
For condition is true, goes inside.

console.log("loop", array1[i], i, array1.length)
Value here is 1, 1, 0, 6

Condition is true it should go inside Ajax and call data on success. But it is returning zero value.

On checking here "console.log(i)"
It is giving output 6 for each loop.

Why is this happening, i have no clue.

whats wrong in code above. Why for 'i'=6 it is taking Ajax request, also for 'i' = 6 condition is false why it is gong inside

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery callback for multiple ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368946/jquery-callback-for-multiple-ajax-calls)

Comment: It does not help

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few details in your snippet to make it run here in SO. The problem you are encountering is caused by the fact that by the time your `success` function steps into action the `for` loop has long finished, leaving you with an `i` and a `getvalue` corresponding to that state. In my snippet I created a **scope in form of an "immediately invoced functional expression" (IIFE)** to preserve the `getvalue` so I can use it in the ensuing call of the `success` function:

```js
const f_ref = 209;
if (f_ref == 209) {
  array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    // console.log("loop", array1[i], i, array1.length);
    (getvalue => $.ajax({ // ==> IIFE, creating a scope for getvalue
      // headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},type: "POST",  
      dataType: 'json',
      // url: "/getReportData",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + getvalue, // mock API
      // data: {getvalue: getvalue},
      //cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        $("#i" + getvalue).val(`i:${i} getvalue:${getvalue} - ${result.name}`);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }))(array1[i]); // ( end of IIFE )
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 300px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Users</h3>
<input type="text" id="i1"></input><br>
<input type="text" id="i2"></input><br>
<input type="text" id="i3"></input><br>
<input type="text" id="i4"></input><br>
<input type="text" id="i5"></input><br>
<input type="text" id="i6"></input>
```

In my snippet I inserted both, the current (unpreserved) `i` and the preserved `getvalue`, into each `input` field to demonstrate that the value of `i` is always `6` - as expected, after the loop has finished.